# How to add SSL to custom domain for S3 (file storage only, not website)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have:

1. Created an S3 bucket called storage.mycustomdomain.com
2. Added a CNAME record per AWS's documentation (via my in-house domain manager) such that http://storage.mycustomdomain.com can be now be used to access any resource in my S3 bucket. Note that this is **http and not https**.

How can I add an SSL cert (via Certificate Manager / Cloudfront / whatever else) so that I can use **https?** Although there is no confidential data per se in the bucket, having the https is really important for credibility.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can leverage CloudFront by integrating it with your S3 bucket. Ensure that you add the necessary CNAME and ACM certificate to enable domain support. Additionally, incorporate a Viewer policy that either enforces `https` or performs a redirect from `https` to `https`.

[image: cloudfront viewer policy]

Please refer below blog post for the step by step guidance.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3